# Is it necessary to have the same spatial resolution of all the bands of an image before classifying the image?

Tags: sentinel-2, random-forest

Is it necessary to have the same spatial resolution of all the bands of an image before classifying the image? In my case, I am working with the 10m and 20m spatial resolution bands of Sentinel-2. I want to apply Random Forest classification using Google Earth Engine.

Comment: Please don't post the same question again, rather edit the original one so that it conforms to GIS SE site rules.